# web SMS configuration - Mail Function

Tags: php, html, sms-gateway

I am using the code below for sending web mails and sms notifications. It works perfectly fine but I would like to ONLY receive the SMS when users choose “A” value from the servicerequired drop-down menu and also don’t want to receive SMS from 8PM to 5AM.

Any help is highly appreciated..

```
<form action="/thankyou.php" name="form1" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="curtime" />
<select name="servicerequired">
<option selected="selected" value="">Please Choose</option>
<option value="A">Replacement</option>
<option value="B">Architectural</option>
<option value="C">Commercial</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
```

and Here is PHP part

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
       $to="myemail@mydomain.com";
       $sms="mymobilenumber@domain.net";
       $subject="Online Quote";
       $from = "webmaster@mydomain.com";
       $curtime = $_REQUEST['curtime'] ;
       $service = $_REQUEST['servicerequired'] ;
       $curtime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
       $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
       "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
          "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
          " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
       $message="message to email";
       $message2="message to sms";
       @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
       @mail($sms, $subject, $message2, $headers);
```

ANS below - special thanks to @Dagon :

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
           $to="myemail@mydomain.com";
           $sms="mymobilenumber@domain.net";
           $subject="Online Quote";
           $from = "webmaster@mydomain.com";
           $curtime = $_REQUEST['curtime'] ;
           $service = $_REQUEST['servicerequired'] ;
           $curtime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
           $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
           "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
              "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
              " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
           $message="message to email";
           $message2="message to sms";
           @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if($_POST['servicerequired']=='A' && (date("G")>5 && date("G")<20)  ){ 
           @mail($sms, $subject, $message2, $headers);
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @andrewsi The question is how to tweak the PHP code above so I will be able to ONLY receive the SMS when users choose “A” value from the servicerequired drop-down menu. 2)how to set the SMS turn off between 8pm to 5am?

Comment: you really cant modify what i have given you to do this? did you even try?

Comment: @Dagon I have to wait until 8PM. right? and I am still not sure about the code. What is the "G" variable?

Comment: G=date hour in 24 hour format. you can parse fake dates to the date function for testing

Comment: @Dagon you are right. I have to do some reasearch on how to do it though. Anyways, is this the right way to integrate your code into the current PHP coding: `if ($_POST['submit']) {
       $to="";
       $sms="";
       $curtime = $_REQUEST['curtime'] ;
       $service = $_REQUEST['servicerequired'] ;
       $curtime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
       @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
$message2="message to sms";
}
if($_POST['servicerequired']=='A' && (date("G")>5 && date("G")<19)  ){ @mail($sms, $subject, $message2, $headers);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($_POST['servicerequired']=='A' && (date("G")>5 && date("G")<19)  ){ 
//SMS STUFF
}
```

Comment: it should two seprate statements. one is for `['servicerequired']=='A'` and the other is for timing. I don't want to recieve any SMS from 8pm to 5am no matter what are the inputs.

Comment: well i imagine you con do that for yourself